# Using Unity 3D in LibGDX

Tags: unity, java, libgdx

Is it possible to use Unity 3D engine with LibGDX when making Android game apps? Is it also possibly used for making 2D games using Unity 3D and LibGDX? I would like to know if it's possibly applicable in Java programming.

Comment: libgdx and unity has same rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Unity and LibGDX would not be used together. Unity is capable of making 2D games, but not with LibGDX. You can program in Unity using something similar to Javascript, called Unityscript, but it's certainly not Java.

It sounds like you need to do significantly more research before embarking on anything too serious.

Comment: It's not really right to call it Javascript. Even though the syntax is similar their semantics are totally different. I always try to call it UnityScript.

Comment: @Grey I haven't used it much so I'm not sure, Unity themselves switch [back](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/) and [forth](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html) between calling it Javascript and UnityScript. But I'm sure you're right.

Comment: The fact that the official word on it is unclear is why he said "try"; calling it UnityScript makes more sense, but it gets called JavaScript usually anyway. Also, I think C# is a lot more like Java, whereas the "Java" in "JavaScript" is just a marketing attempt to deliberately mislead.

Comment: I believe that Unity is most accurately called a different domain-specific implementation of ECMAscript.  Javascript is a different implemention (the most common, and recently less domain-specific).  Unity's script implements features from the ECMA standard that are unavailable in javascript, such as flow control through coroutines.  @Grey is right, the semantics aren't the same, but they have a close common ancestor.